# How can I change the TopNavigationAction icon size

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm starting to use ui kitten.
I'm trying to change the size of the icon for the `TopNavigation`  leftControl. I'm using `arrow-ios-back-outline` for the `TopNavigationAction` icon but it looks smaller than a normal back arrow on iOS so I tried to change the size by adding a size attribute to my icon

This is my renderLeftControl code:

```
const renderedIcon = props => {
  return <Icon name="arrow-ios-back-outline" size={200} {...props} />;
};

const renderLeftControl = ({
  onCommand,
  ...iucProps
}): React.ReactElement<TopNavigationActionProps> => {
  return (
    <TopNavigationAction
      style={{ backgroundColor: "magenta" }}
      icon={renderedIcon}
      onPress={onCommand}
    />
  );
};
```

Unfortunately it appears the prop is being completely ignored because the icon always gets rendered with the same size.

I suppose I'm doing it the wrong way but I'm struggling to find the right way of doing it.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try using `fontSize` css property on `<Icon>`

Comment: No luck @Farhan. It still renders the icon the same size always. Also it is important to note the icon set is svg based, so I think `fontSize` is probably no the option to use. Thank you anyway.

Comment: What is `TopNavigationAction` ? Your custom Topbar??

Comment: It's a component from `react-native-ui-kitten`

Answer (score 1):

The Icon you're trying to use relies on `react-native-svg` elements, so in this case you're able to use `width` and `height` properties. Also, see other [common properties](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#common-props)